# Python to select the best fantasy rugby team

Tags: python

**I am trying to select the best possible combination of players for a fantasy rugby team.**

I have already made a prediction for the number of fantasy points they are going to get for the next week (the final column, 'pts'), now I want Python to run through all the combination of players to select the highest scoring team.

There are several rules that have to be satisfied:

- Can only have 4 players from each country (there are 6 countries).
- Maximum budget (in my case, 246.4).
- There are 15 starting players.
- You can pick 3 substitutes who only earn half points (but cost the same). You dont have to use these 3. (I understands this complicates the model: my thoughts here are maybe to run the model 3 times - once with 1 sub, once with 2, and once with 3 subs).
- There is a minimum/maximum number of players in each position

  | Position | Min players | Max players |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | FB | 1 | 2 |
  | C | 2 | 4 |
  | W | 2 | 4 |
  | FH | 1 | 2 |
  | SH | 1 | 2 |
  | BR | 3 | 6 |
  | SR | 2 | 4 |
  | P | 2 | 4 |
  | H | 1 | 2 |

The data itself looks like this (about 200 rows worth).

| Country | Name | Position | Value | Pts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wales | T. Faletau | BR | 17.5 | 74.7 |
| France | G. Alldrit | BR | 17.3 | 55.8 |
| Ireland | C. Stander | BR | 16.9 | 55.2 |
| France | C. Ollivion | BR | 15.8 | 55.1 |
| Wales | J. Tipuric | BR | 15.6 | 54.7 |

I'll be honest, I'm new to this and haven't got that far. I've tried to follow some tutorials using python in jupyter notebook but I can't find a use case that's the same as mine.

My desired output is a list of the highest possible points scoring team, according to the rules I listed.

Any help much appreciated, even if it's directing me to reading.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code in your question, it is a bit difficult to give you code to work with, but I have outlined my suggested approach:

1. **Organize the player data into dictionaries**: I suggest making the keys of these dictionaries the table headers and the values would be the corresponding value for each player.

```py
{"Country": "Wales", "Name": "T. Faletau", "Position": "BR", "Value": 17.5, "Points": 74.7}
...
```

2. **Organize the dictionaries of player data by position**: You can create a dictionary with the various positions as the keys. The values of the dictionary would then be a list of dictionaries of players who play at the position, which is the key.

```py
data = {"BR": [{"Country": "Wales", "Name": "T. Faletau", "Position": "BR", "Value": 17.5, "Points": 74.7}, ...]}
```

3. **Create an empty dictionary for the final roster and for additional players**: How you want to structure this dictionary is up to you. I myself would imitate the dictionary in Step (2), with each position as the key and a list of player dictionaries as the values.

```py
roster = {"BR": [], ...}
final_roster = {"BR": [], ...}
```

4. **For each position, run through each player dictionary in the corresponding list**: Check each player dictionary and append the player dictionaries which have the highest value corresponding to the *Points* key. I myself would sort the list from highest *Points* value to the lowest, then just take the appropriate number of items. For example, for the *BR* position:

```py
for plist in data["BR"]:
    data["BR"] = sorted(plist, key=lambda k: k['Points']) 
    final_roster["BR"] = data["BR"][:3]
    roster["BR"] = data["BR"][3:6]
```

5. **Once `final_roster` is filled with the maximum number of players for each position, run through all the players and take the players with the highest number of points**: This is almost the same as Step (4), except that now you are disregarding positions. So you can implement the same strategy, where you organize the data, then slice the list.

Hopefully this helps. Again, this would be too much to write out an entire script and it would not be worth it for either party. In the future, however, I would recommend asking questions on more specific topics to get better answers.